# Rxjs 4 simple debug with console.log

Tags: rxjs

I'm quite new at rxjs stuff so please be patience :).

```
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup');
    source.filter(function(x){
      console.log('filter with', x);
      return true;
    });
    var subscription = source.subscribe(
      function (x) {
        console.log('Next: keyup!',x.keyCode);
      },
      function (err) {
        console.log('Error: %s', err);
      },
      function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });
```

whats the right way to debug inside filter
I dont see any *filter with*
in the console

I've also tried with

```
var source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keyup');
    source.filter(function(x){
      console.log('filter with', x);
      return true;
    });
    source.do(x => console.log('do with',x));
    var subscription = source.subscribe(
      function (x) {
        console.log('Next: keyup!',x.keyCode);
      },
      function (err) {
        console.log('Error: %s', err);
      },
      function () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });
```

with no lucky

Can you give me an hint please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

source.filter() is creating a new Observable, yet you only subscribe to the original Observable, source. Observables that aren't subscribed to are not carried out

You have to do something like this:

```
source.filter()
      .do()
      .subscribe()
```